# Find days in a quarter in a date range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

My worksheet looks like this

[image]

I was able to get the total quarters between a date range as shown in cell D4. I created a UDF and it works well.

```
Function GetDayPerQtr(ReimDt As Date, HoldDt As Date) As String
    Dim Qtr As Integer
    Dim QtrStDt As Date
    Dim QtrEndDate As Date
    Dim TotalQtrs As Long
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    Qtr = DetermineQuarter(ReimDt)
    QtrEndDate = DateSerial(Year(ReimDt), (Qtr * 3) + 1, 0)
    
    If QtrEndDate <= HoldDt Then
        TotalQtrs = DateDiff("q", ReimDt, HoldDt)
        
        If TotalQtrs > 1 Then
            QtrStDt = ReimDt
            
            For i = 1 To TotalQtrs
                Qtr = DetermineQuarter(QtrStDt)
                If Qtr = 2 Or Qtr = 3 Then
                    QtrEndDate = DateSerial(Year(QtrStDt), Qtr * 3, 30)
                Else
                    QtrEndDate = DateSerial(Year(QtrStDt), Qtr * 3, 31)
                End If
                
                tmp = tmp & ", " & (QtrEndDate - QtrStDt + 1)
                QtrStDt = QtrEndDate + 1
            Next i
            
            tmp = tmp & ", " & (HoldDt - QtrStDt + 1)
            tmp = Mid(tmp, 2)
        Else
            tmp = QtrEndDate - ReimDt
            QtrStDt = QtrEndDate + 1
            tmp = tmp & ", " & (HoldDt - QtrStDt + 1)
        End If
    Else
        tmp = HoldDt - ReimDt
    End If
    
    GetDayPerQtr = tmp
End Function

Function DetermineQuarter(Dt As Date) As Integer
    Dim inputDate As Date
    Dim quarter As Integer
    Dim inputMonth As Integer
    
    inputDate = Dt
    inputMonth = Month(inputDate)
    
    If inputMonth >= 1 And inputMonth <= 3 Then
        quarter = 1
    ElseIf inputMonth >= 4 And inputMonth <= 6 Then
        quarter = 2
    ElseIf inputMonth >= 7 And inputMonth <= 9 Then
        quarter = 3
    ElseIf inputMonth >= 10 And inputMonth <= 12 Then
        quarter = 4
    End If
    DetermineQuarter = quarter
End Function
```

Now I am trying to get the result as shown in green cells based on the start date and end date.

So basically, the values which I am showing in cell D4 should go into respective columns.

I tried various combination of the above code and ended up getting confused. Can someone help me or guide me how to achieve what I want? I am open to both VBA and Excel Formula suggestions.

I also tried to incorporate a logic around the below but got stuck.

```
'=GetTotalDaysInQtr("Q1",2020,B4,C4)
Function GetTotalDaysInQtr(Qtr As String, Yr As Long, ReimDt As Date, HoldDt As Date) As Long

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put true dates on the sheet you can use a formula like this:

`=IF(AND($B3>=M$2,$A3<=N$2),MIN(N$2,$B3)-MAX(M$2,$A3),0)`

[image]

Creating the quarter dates can be achieved with the formula as well using the `EDATE` function with a start date like 1.1.2020 and a months parameter of 3.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Seems like I over engineered what I wanted. Never thought of it this way.